# How to parse this wikipedia response?

Tags: android, json, android-json

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "25675557": {
                "pageid": 25675557,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Cricket",
                "extract": "Cricket is a bat-and-ball game played between two teams of eleven players each on a cricket field, at the centre of which is a rectangular 22-yard-long (20 metres) pitch with a target at each end called the wicket (a set of three wooden stumps upon which two bails sit). "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code I tried :

```
public void getJSON(final String city) throws JSONException {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=" + city);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader reader =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer(1024);
                String tmp = "";
                while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    json.append(tmp).append("\n");
                }
                reader.close();

                data = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                if (data.getInt("cod") != 200) {
                    System.out.println("Cancelled");
                    return null;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void Void) {
            if (data != null) {
                Log.d("my weather received", data.toString());
                try {
                    //JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONObject forecastArray = data.getJSONObject("query");
                    System.out.println(forecastArray);

                    JSONArray pagesArray = forecastArray.getJSONArray("pages");
                    // JSONArray idArray = pagesArray.getJSONArray(0);
                    //JSONArray idArray = pagesArray.get(0);
                    System.out.println(pagesArray);

                    JSONObject obj = pagesArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    System.out.println(obj);

                    //JSONObject weatherarray = data.getJSONObject("pages");
                    //JSONObject weather = weatherarray.getJSONObject(0);
                    // final String des = weather.getString("description");

                     /*for (int i = 0; i < forecastArray.length(); i++) {
                     JSONObject dailyForecast = forecastArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     JSONObject tempObject = dailyForecast.getJSONObject("main");
                     minTemp = tempObject.getDouble("min");
                     maxTemp = tempObject.getDouble("max");
                     //add these minTemp and maxTemp to array or the
                     //way you want to use
                 }*/
                     System.out.println("Temp Value : "+" : ");

                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textvw.setText("");
                        }
                     });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("GetFeedTask", "Error:" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: Can't you use Gson to simplify your parsing ?

Comment: 03-09 16:02:38.501 11672-11672/com.example.a25100059.wikipedia E/GetFeedTask: Error:Value {"45139":{"pageid":45139,"ns":0,"title":"Chennai","extract":"Chennai ( ( listen); formerly known as Madras  ( listen) or ) is the capital of the Indian state of Tamil Nadu. Located on the Coromandel Coast off the Bay of Bengal, it is one of the biggest cultural, economic and educational centres in South India. Aission."}} at pages of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: this is the error i am getting.  "pages of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray"

Comment: it says "pages" is not a JSONArray but it is a JSONObject.

Comment: i need just extract to be displayed.

Comment: {"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"25675557":{"pageid":25675557,"ns":0,"title":"Cricket","extract":"Cricket........"}}}}                   The problem is i need to access extract object but inside the pages object id is given  and id is different for each search.. so please tell me how to access extract.

Comment: Just use GSON, please.

Comment: see.. this id 25675557 is different for each search. In my code city is a variable and it will take value from my textview that i will enter and search it.. for each search id will be different so how we will going to access extract. ,"query":{"pages":{"25675557":{"pageid":25675557,"ns":0,"title":"Cricket","extract":"Cricket........"}}}}

Comment: please help me..

Comment: i don't have any idea about GSON.

Comment: because you have different page name and size  you must send your array in []

Answer (score 2):

The exception is because the response does not contain JSON Array. Change your

```
JSONArray pagesArray = forecastArray.getJSONArray("pages");
```

to

```
JSONObject pagesArray = forecastArray.getJSONObject("pages");
```

and I believe that you're trying to get keys which are dynamic. You cloud get the objects using `JSONObject.getKeys()` like below.

```
Iterator keys = pagesArray.keys();

while(keys.hasNext()) {
    String dynamicKey = (String)keys.next();
    JSONObject jObj = pagesArray.getJSONObject(dynamicKey);

    //Get other attributes by jObj.getString() method.
}
```

Try and let me know if it works.

Comment: while(keys.hasNext()) {
                            String dynamicKey = (String)keys.next();
                            JSONObject jObj = pagesArray.getJSONObject(dynamicKey);
                            final JSONObject sobj = jObj.getJSONObject("extract");
                            System.out.println(sobj);
                            final String des = sobj.getString("extract");
                            System.out.println("Temp Value : " +sobj );

Comment: Thank you sir.. I got my answer.

Comment: @KomalGupta did my answer help you? Please accept if it did :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear enough. you try to assign a JSONobject to a JSONArray

```
JSONArray pagesArray = forecastArray.getJSONArray("pages");
```

Replace by

```
JSONObject pagesArray = forecastArray.JSONObject("pages");
```

the data of a JSONArray are between [] and not {}.

Comment: "pages": {
            "25675557": {
                "pageid": 25675557,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Cricket",
                "extract"...................."}}}   the id is different for each search . so how i will access extract.

Comment: you know the id in advance before starting to parse?

Answer (score 0):

your error is in :

```
        JSONArray pagesArray = forecastArray.getJSONArray("pages");
```

Your problem is that you getJSONArray while pages are a JsonObject in your data .if your "pages" is a array in your data you must send it in [] from server like this:

```
    {
"batchcomplete": "",
"query": {
    "pages": [ {
            "pageid": 25675557,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Cricket",
            "extract": "Cricket is a bat-and-ball game played between two teams of eleven players each on a cricket field, at the centre of which is a rectangular 22-yard-long (20 metres) pitch with a target at each end called the wicket (a set of three wooden stumps upon which two bails sit). "
        },
 {
            "pageid": 25675557,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Cricket",
            "extract": "Cricket is a bat-and-ball game played between two teams of eleven players each on a cricket field, at the centre of which is a rectangular 22-yard-long (20 metres) pitch with a target at each end called the wicket (a set of three wooden stumps upon which two bails sit). "
        }
    ]
}
}
```

and in android :

```
 try {
        //JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONObject forecastArray = data.getJSONObject("query");
        System.out.println(forecastArray);

        JSONArray pagesArray = forecastArray.getJSONArray("pages");
        System.out.println(pagesArray);


        for (int k = 0; k < pagesArray.length(); k++) {

            try {
                JSONObject object = pagesArray.getJSONObject(k);
                String pageid = object.getString("pageid");
                String ns = object.getString("ns");
                String title = object.getString("title");
                String extract = object.getString("extract");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("GetFeedTask", "Error:" + e.getMessage());
    }
```